# Decrypt file in mvc. encrypted in windows store

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-store

I have a file encrypted using windows.security.cryptography class and methods. I want to decrypt this file in mvc system.security.cryptography.

Comment: We want to know what you've tried 

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, read the [How-to-ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide carefully and improve your question accordingly, paying special attention to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If someone else encrypted the file with a "perfect" (uncrackable) algorithm, you cannot decrypt it. That's the goal of encryption, ain't it?